# Set __autoload to use a private function of a class

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation, autoload

I have a class with a private function that i don't want to be called directly.

**Example class:**

```
class Importer{
    private function import(){}
}
```

Now i want to send a parameter passed to `__autoload()` to `import` function of `Importer` class.
I also know regularly is impossible and illogical to call a private function but do you know any solution or trick to keep `import()` private or preventing direct access ?

Comment: Why don't you just have a private method like `processImport` and a public method called `import` to work around this problem?

Comment: Autoloaders cannot access private methods either. You can't have it both ways. It's either fully private, or not at all. And if you feel the need to make exceptions for yourself, the decision to make the method private was misguided in the first place. -- If you meant something else, please reexplain, from the beginning.

Comment: @Treffynnon: So how it can solve the problem? the `import` function is still accessible directly

Comment: @OmidAmraei yeah that is what I am asking. I see what you are driving at now. As mario says - not possible.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If your import should happen exactly one time, but has to be triggered from the outside ( from the autoloader or wherever ), calling import() from the constructor seems a good way for me. But why do you want to do that from within the autoloader?

Comment: @thatsdisgusting: i want just want to keep all importing operation encapsulated in a class. calling `import()` on constructor of what ?

Comment: Never mind, i misunderstood your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Importer {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'import') );
    }

    private function import($class) {
        include $class . '.php';
    }
}

$importer = new Importer();

$obj = new testclass();

var_dump($obj);
```

Output

> object(testclass)#2 (0) { }